# Compiler error: 'expected expression' while editing Linux pre-processor statment

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor

I am attempting to add a conditional statement to some per-processor code but I am not sure why it wont compile. Here is the un-altered code:

```
static struct i2c_board_info ccwmx51_i2c_devices[] __initdata = {

    {
        // Use erdigitemp2 driver for device id 0x48 (digital temperature sensor)
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("erdigitemp2", 0x48)
    },
    {
        // Use erdigitemp2 driver for device id 0x4c (digital temperature sensor)
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("erdigitemp2", 0x4c)
    },
    {
        // Use tvp5150 driver for device id 0x5c (camera decoder)
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("tvp5150tj", 0xb8 >> 1)
    },
#if defined(CONFIG_TJTKMJ_LSM303DLHC)
        {
                // STMICROELECTRONICS LSM303DLHC e-compass
                // accelerometer
                I2C_BOARD_INFO("lsm303dlhc_acc", 0x19)
        },
        {
                // magnetometer
                I2C_BOARD_INFO("lsm303dlhc_mag", 0x1e)
        },
#endif  
#if defined(CONFIG_INPUT_MMA7455L) || defined(CONFIG_INPUT_MMA7455L_MODULE)
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("mma7455l", 0x1d),
        .irq = IOMUX_TO_IRQ(MX51_PIN_GPIO1_7),
    },
#endif
#if defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753) || defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753_MODULE)
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("wm8753", 0x1A),
        },
#endif
#if defined (CONFIG_MXC_CAMERA_MICRON111_1) || defined(CONFIG_MXC_CAMERA_MICRON111_1_MODULE)
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("mt9v111_1", 0xB8>>1),
    },
#endif
#if defined (CONFIG_MXC_CAMERA_MICRON111_2) || defined(CONFIG_MXC_CAMERA_MICRON111_2_MODULE)
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("mt9v111_2", 0x90>>1),
    },
#endif
};
```

and my alterations are a simple if statement:

```
if (hardware_id() == 0) {
    #if defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753) || defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753_MODULE)
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("wm8753", 0x1A),
            },
    #endif
}
```

The compiler error is:

error: expected expression before 'if'

Comment: You can't put statements inside variable initializations.

Comment: Okay so all this method is doing is initializing a bunch of variables?

Comment: It's just initialization one variable, an array.

Comment: It's an array of structures, and each of those `{ ... }` things is one structure initializer.

Comment: `I2C_BOARD_INFO` is a macro that expands into the structure members.

Comment: @Barmar Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe you can create an empty element when initializing, and then in the code you can use an `if` statement to fill it in. It really depends on how the `ccwmx51_i2c_devices` array is used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but it should at least compile.

```
#if defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753) || defined(CONFIG_SND_SOC_IMX_CCWMX51_WM8753_MODULE)
if (hardware_id() == 0){
    I2C_BOARD_INFO("wm8753", 0x1A),
}else{
    //something
},
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no that won't compile. I wish it were that simple though :) No I am having to chase down the array and pull the value out there were it is being used. I need to create two new arrays with the data and blah blah blah its annoying.